# Cross-platform open-source C or C++ library for playing tracker music

Tags: c++, c, audio, bass, bass.dll

I need a cross-platform (supporting at least Windows and Linux) library for playing tracker music (formats like *.mod and *.xm) from within a C++ program.

It sounds weird, but a google search really didn't bring any good results! Only thing I could find was the [BASS audio library](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html) but there are two problems with it: first, I don't really need support for all the other formats, just tracker music; and second, it's not open source.

Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Comment: See libmodplug (XMMS version): http://sourceforge.net/projects/modplug-xmms/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a codebase just take a look at public repositories ;)

One of the most popular website is github [link](https://github.com/search?q=music%20xm&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Everything&language=C%2b%2b)